# Rest Query to list all containers in all namespace in Kubernetes

Tags: rest, kubernetes, openshift

I know there is `kubectl` command to list containers in all the namespaces:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath={.items[*].spec.containers[*].name}
```

is there a way to get all the containers in all namespaces using rest query?

Answer (score 2):

You cant query the REST API for containers directly, since the smallest unit you can manage is a Pod, as is the same in your `kubectl` example.

You could however query all Pods and filter using a tool like jq. So obviously, replacing your `$TOKEN` and `$CLUSTER` as appropriate, the following should work:

`curl -XGET  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json" https://$CLUSTER:8443/api/v1/pods?limit=500 | jq '.items[] .spec .containers[] .name'`

Not sure how the above has any benefit over using the cli though. On a side note, if your using the `oc` tool, set the `--loglevel=9` option and you will be able to see what request is being sent to the server.